# Why can't Discover find my extension or What is Discover looking for?

Tags: joomla-4.x, installation, discover

As a result of a mistake I made in the way I set up an extensions symlinks my extension was not being found when using the Discover feature of Joomla, this lead me to stepping through the installer code to find the cause.

Therefore my question is Why can't Discover find my extension or What is Discover looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is Discover is looking for a manifest file with the .xml in your extensions directory, eg.`myextname.xml is searched for, and it must have valid XML elements.

In my examples here I am working with a Component but the process is pretty much the same with each type of extension having their own `discover()` method in an adaptor of their own, e.g. `\libraries\src\Installer\Adapter\ComponentAdapter.php`

A list of possible extensions is built by traversing specific directories to create a list of extension names.

```
$site_components  = Folder::folders(JPATH_SITE . '/components');
$admin_components = Folder::folders(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components');
$api_components = Folder::folders(JPATH_API . '/components');
```

Once it has a list of components will then attempt to check for the existence of the .xml file.

```
foreach ($site_components as $component) 
{
    if (file_exists(JPATH_SITE . '/components/' . $component . '/' . str_replace('com_', '', $component) . '.xml')) 
    {...}
```

If the .xml file is found it is then passed to the Installer class that again checks that it exists and attempts to the read the xml to be returned. If your manifest file has invalid xml element(s) it will silently fail and not be displayed. From `\libraries\src\Installer\Installer.php`

```
public static function parseXMLInstallFile($path)
{
    // Check if xml file exists.
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Read the file to see if it's a valid component XML file
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($path);

    if (!$xml) {
        return false;
    }
```